# How do I fix my grid?

Tags: python, tkinter

For a board game program I am creating, I'm drawing a board by looping through rows and columns using canvas.create_rectangle. I want it to look like a grid so each rectangle has a border.

What I have currently is:

```
def draw_board(canvas, width, height, n):
    for row in range(n+1):
        for col in range(n+1):
            canvas.create_rectangle(row*height/n,col*width/n,(row+1)*height/n,(col+1)*width/n,width=0,fill='white',outline='black')

from Tkinter import *
import math

width = 500
height = 500
n = 10

window=Tk()
window.title('Color grid')

canvas=Canvas(window,width=width,height=height,highlightthickness=0)
canvas.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=5)

draw_board(canvas, width, height, 10)

window.mainloop()
```

However, the outline does not appear when I run the program and I ultimately just get a white window.

Comment: Post the whole code.

Comment: it seems to me that it is easier to make a grid with lines than rectangles

Comment: also your width = 0 might mess your outline up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just look at your code.

```
canvas.create_rectangle(row*height/n,col*width/n,(row+1)*height/n,(col+1)*width/n,width=0,fill='white',outline='black')
```

From the [TKinter](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/create_rectangle.html) reference:

> **width** - *Width of the border. Default is 1 pixel. Use width=0 to make the* border invisible.

You are setting the width equal to 0. So it's invisible. That's why you are seeing just a white window.

EDIT: Also, you don't need to put `outline='black'` as that is the default.